# LTspice how show FFT of n004-n008? Expression? How? Example?

Tags: circuit-analysis

In LTspice, how can one show the FFT of the difference v(n004-v(n008) i.e v(n004,n008)? Expression? How? Example? What are the steps for bringing up such an expression so it can be FFT'd? The computer says

Error on line nnn : v(n004)-v(n008)
Unknown parameter "n004"

or

Error on line mmm : v(n004)-v(n008)
Unknown parameter "n008"

FFT expressions directive trace

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is use a ***voltage dependent voltage source*** (VDVS) to obtain a single node that you can use for the FFT.

In the component picker they are listed as 'e'. Add one to your schematic and connect the inputs (connections on the left side) to the two nodes you want to get the difference of, the + input to one node, - input to the other. Ground the - output and label the + output. Now hold Ctl and right click the VDVS. In the menu that pops up set *Value* to 1.

You can now run your simulation, plot the + output of VDVS and do an FFT on it.
[image: Using VDVS to get FFT]

Another thing you can do with a VDVS is make it have gain/attenuation.

By using a formula for *Value* you can have a parameter to set the gain in decibels. This can be useful with FFT if you're interested in the relative value of the distortion products. For example, you're looking at the output of an amplifier that has a gain of +26 dB, in the FFT you may be more interested in how far below the fundamental the harmonics are rather than their absolute values. By setting the VDVS to have a gain of -26 dB the fundamental will be at 0 dB and the harmonics will be relative to 0 dB.

In this example there are two .PARAMs, one with the formula and a separate one to set the gain in dB. I do it that way so I can stick the formula out of the way on the schematic and just have the gain set .PARAM near the VDVS, it just makes it a bit cleaner in use.
[image: VDVS with gain]

FFT with gain set to put fundamental at 0 dB, the 2nd and 3rd harmonics are ~ 90 dB down.
[image: FFT with fundamental at 0dB]

Comment: "*As far as I know you can't do that directly.*" -- it can be done, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, the `Nxxx` notation indicates that LTspice is using the default node numbering and, if these nodes are to be plotted, you'd do better to label them, because LTspice renumbers them as soon as there is the slightest change in the schematic. You may end up with the same nodes, you may not, it's a lottery, one that you'd rather not depend on. As soon as you add labels, those will be immutable and will stay plotted forever (until changed, that is).

Then, to plot the difference you could do it by adding an additional source (VCVS/VCCS, behavioural source, whatever other fancy), or you could perform the FFTs for the nodes in question and then, when opening up the FFT window, choose or rename the waveforms to be a difference.

Example: For the following schematic:

[image: difference FFT example]

`V1, V2` are two, different sines with different amplitudes, `E1, B1` are set to give the difference `a-b`. When you choose *View > FFT* (ignore the black bands, they're rendering artifacts), be sure to select all the quantities that you need to perform FFT on. Here, you are interested in `V(a,b)`, so you need `V(a)` and `V(b)` to be selected. `V(x)` and `V(y)` represent the FFTs of `E1` and `B1`, respectively, so they are chosen for the sake of comparison. Also, it only shows the voltages because that's what I chose to save (see the `.save` command).

[image: FFT window]

After the FFT plot window appears, either modify `V(a)` to `V(a,b)`, for example, or add another trace where you specify `V(a,b)`, directly. This is how the three quantities look like:

[image: 3 little FFTs]

`V(x)` and `V(y)` completely overlap, while `V(a,b)` has only a tad higher noise floor, which is due to not turning waveform compression off (.opt plotwinsize=0`) and not imposing a tighter timestep (e.g.` 10u`), so what you're seeing is the result of the numeric residuals for the imposed precision.